# Looping through multiple php arrays to change value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array `$users` as such:

```
  [0] => Array (
    [userid] => 1
    [score] => 9.9
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [userid] => 2
    [score] => 9
  )
```

For each user, I then retrieve items and store them into an array, `$results`:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $items = getItems($user['userid']);
  $results[] = $items:
}
```

The `$results` array ends up looking like this:

```
[0] => Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [itemid] => 1
    [rating] => 9.9
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [itemid] => 2
    [rating] => 9
  )
)
[1] => Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [itemid] => 3
    [rating] => 8.5
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [itemid] => 2
    [rating] => 7.5
  )
)
```

What I would like to do, is weigh the item rating with the user score. So, for each item, the rating would be multiplied by user score * 0.1.

What I've tried is this:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $items = getItems($user['id']);
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    $item['rating'] = $item['rating'] * $user['score'] * 0.1;
  }
  $results[] = $items:
}
```

but to no avail. What am I doing wrong and how do I get the desired result?

Comment: I think you are asking questions every step of your process. Most of your questions (including the one you deleted) are duplicates. I think there should also be an effort from your end to learn and solve your questions.

Comment: I've deleted the first dupe because it was almost exactly the same as the question you pointed me to. The other one was a bit different so I marked it as dupe. I always do a search before posting, but I don't always use the right terms or wording so it's difficult to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in foreach the value is `passed by value`. So even if you change the data inside of an array inside the loop it will not be reflected. So you have to use `&` before `$item` to pass the array data by `reference`.

You can learn more about it here http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php